# Can I use an RF Receiver to any pin on an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, rf

I have a project that uses a nodemcu and it includes an rf receiver, I created the pcb board already etc etc... so I've already chosen D7 (GPI013) before reading on connecting the rf receiver and found that a lot of people are saying to connect it to the interrupt pin and for the case of an Arduino it was pin 2 and for the nodemcu it's D3 (GPIO0).

**UPDATE:** the pin in question is the data pin for the rf receiver, this would be connected to D7 (GPIO13) because of the trace on the board. it is purely used for receiving the data it picks up and giving it to the nodemcu to handle.

Can I just use a different pin which in my example is D7 (GPIO13) or does it **HAVE** to be an interrupt pin?

*Side note: I'm aware of the advantage of using an interrupt pin where that it takes priority over code running.*

Comment: What does the pin do?  Is it used to notify the program that data is ready? if so, then you will have to poll that pin rather then take advantage of an interrupt, and this will be a bit slower, but I have no idea if that will effect your project since we dont know what your project is, or what that pin is even doing.

Comment: you did not say what is the purpose of the pin in question

Comment: you can hook it to the ESP, which can use any pin as an interrupt, and side-steps the middle man uno.

Comment: Thank you @dandavis how would I go about using D7 (GPIO13) as the pin interrupt in this case, when testing with the uno I would just define the enablereceiver as 0 which equals pin 2 on the board using RC Switch.